# How to immediately apply tintColor to iOS navigation back button text

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I'm working on an iOS application that allows a user to change the primary accent color. When the user selects the accent color, all currently displayed elements that contain the accent color need to be updated. I've got a solution that works for everything except the navigation bar's back button text. I can change the title text color and the left carat changes color as expected.

When I use the code below, the left carat immediately changes but the text next to it doesn't.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = accentColor
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = navBarColor
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: anotherColor,
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: someFont
    ];
```

Also, prior to the above code, the UIAppearance proxy for UIBarButtonItem has titleTextAttributes set - but these don't apply to views that are already displayed.

What am I missing here? If the view is dismissed completely and reloaded, the back button text takes on the tintColor. Is there a way to do this without adding a custom backBarButtonItem?

iOS 9+ - swift solution appreciated, but objc is fine, too. This part of the application is storyboard-based.

**EDIT**: Updated code and description.

**UPDATE**: The behaviour is different between iOS 11.2 and 10.3. In iOS 11.2, the left and right bar button text color does not update based on the tint for any of the views in the stack until they are reloaded. In iOS 10.3, the colors update but not for the visible view.

Comment: That’s strange, the navigationBar tintColor definitely changes the label colour too (and the result should be immediately visible). Are you changing the tintColor anywhere else in your code prior? If you could post any other relevant code (anything you’re doing with the navigation bar’s appearance) that would help.

Comment: @PeteMorris I was stepping on my own toes here. At another place in the code I was setting the titleTextAttributes for UIBarButtonItems when contained in UINavigationBars via the UIAppearanceProxy. When I set the foreground color of the titleTextAttributes, it took precedence over the tintColor that was applied to the navigationBar.